# Managed metadata column, auto-complete

Tags: search, search-results

I just got a requirements for custom search.

Input box - Managed metadata type, meaning as you type the customer name it starts suggesting. So first you pick the customer name after type few letters in the input box (this can managed metadata type field). Then click Search to view records for that customer in Datasheet view.

How would I go by doing this?

Comment: Do you need to get data from SharePoint search service? Or just make a filter on a list view?

Comment: I am open either solution. If I can have a list displays data only after user picks vendor name from managed metadata navigation that would be fine too. If that's not possible then a search tabular result and input box being managed metadata type.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Have you looked at autocomplete options? (http://spautosuggestion.codeplex.com/) Does it have to be a Datasheet?